# Java fx frop drag and drop issue

Tags: javafx-2

How to do drag and drop within one listview

I have only one list view (Ed. "player")

My requirement is to move up and down in the same player list

Please find the code i have used

(Not: I am using jdk 1.7 with default javafx)

Example:(player = listView)

```
listView.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            Dragboard dragBoard = listView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

            content.putString(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue());

            dragBoard.setContent(content);

        }
    });

    listView.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent dragEvent) {
            System.out.println("setOnDragDone left");

        }
    });

    listView.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent dragEvent) {
            System.out.println("setOnDragEntered left");

        }
    });

    listView.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent dragEvent) {
            System.out.println("setOnDragExited left");

            listView.setBlendMode(null);
        }
    });

    listView.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent dragEvent) {
            System.out.println("setOnDragOver left");

            dragEvent.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
        }
    });

    listView.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent dragEvent) {

                String context = dragEvent.getDragboard().getString();


                dragEvent.setDropCompleted(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

I am new to javafx

Would you please help on this regard

Answer (score 3):

Don't register the drag handlers on the `ListView`: you will have no way of knowing which cells the drag started and ended on. Instead, you need to register the handlers on the cells. The details get a little tricky, but the basic idea is to create a cell factory in which you create the custom cells; here you can set up the drag and drop handlers.

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class DragAndDropListView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add("Item "+i);
        }

        final IntegerProperty dragFromIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);

        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {

            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> lv) {
                final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item,  empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setText(null);
                        } else {
                            setText(item);
                        }
                    }
                };

                cell.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
                            dragFromIndex.set(cell.getIndex());
                            Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                            ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
                            cc.putString(cell.getItem());
                            db.setContent(cc);
                            // Java 8 only:
//                          db.setDragView(cell.snapshot(null, null));
                        }
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        if (dragFromIndex.get() >= 0 && dragFromIndex.get() != cell.getIndex()) {
                            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                        }
                    }
                });


                // highlight drop target by changing background color:
                cell.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        if (dragFromIndex.get() >= 0 && dragFromIndex.get() != cell.getIndex()) {
                            // should really set a style class and use an external style sheet,
                            // but this works for demo purposes:
                            cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gold;");
                        }
                    }
                });

                // remove highlight:
                cell.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        cell.setStyle("");
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {

                        int dragItemsStartIndex ;
                        int dragItemsEndIndex ;
                        int direction ;
                        if (cell.isEmpty()) {
                            dragItemsStartIndex = dragFromIndex.get();
                            dragItemsEndIndex = listView.getItems().size();
                            direction = -1;
                        } else {
                            if (cell.getIndex() < dragFromIndex.get()) {
                                dragItemsStartIndex = cell.getIndex();
                                dragItemsEndIndex = dragFromIndex.get() + 1 ;
                                direction = 1 ;
                            } else {
                                dragItemsStartIndex = dragFromIndex.get();
                                dragItemsEndIndex = cell.getIndex() + 1 ;
                                direction = -1 ;
                            }
                        }

                        List<String> rotatingItems = listView.getItems().subList(dragItemsStartIndex, dragItemsEndIndex);
                        List<String> rotatingItemsCopy = new ArrayList<>(rotatingItems);
                        Collections.rotate(rotatingItemsCopy, direction);
                        rotatingItems.clear();
                        rotatingItems.addAll(rotatingItemsCopy);
                        dragFromIndex.set(-1);
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        dragFromIndex.set(-1);
                        listView.getSelectionModel().select(event.getDragboard().getString());
                    }
                });


                return cell ;
            }


        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("drag-and-drop-list.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This will enable you to drag any element and drop it onto any other. For example dragging the third item in the list

[image]

and dropping it on the first item results in this:

[image]

In Java 8 you can also add the line

```
db.setDragView(cell.snapshot(null, null));
```

to the `setOnDragDetected(...)` method to get a better visual on the drag.

Comment: Hi James, I tried your code drag and drop is not working. Will you please give me a clear example

Comment: I copied this directly from my IDE: it was working just fine for me. "Not working" is not very helpful. What goes wrong?

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your reply. My requirement is to drag the 3rd item in the list and drop it into 1 st position. I am able to drag the 3rd item but cannot able to drop it into exact position i.e. as 1 st item in the list

Comment: Also added code to highlight the drop target, in case not being able to see where you are dropping clearly is the issue

Comment: Hi James, For the above requirement if i have two seperate list. Drag the 3rd item from the first list and drop it to the 4th item in the second list. Please suggest some ideas. How to find the index in the second list while dropping.